# How to avoid hit rate limits when using firebase authentication in the backend server?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I implement user signup logic in my nodejs backend server. It uses firebase for username and password signup. Below is the code used in nodejs:

```
var firebaseClient = require('firebase');
firebaseClient.initializeApp(config)
firebaseClient.auth(). createUserWithEmailAndPassword(req.body.email, req.body.password).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
})
```

the problem for this approach is that firebase has a usage limit which is 100 accounts/IP address/hour. All users who signup in my application will go to my nodejs server first. That means firebase will think there is only one user. It will meet the usage limit very easily. I know I can put the signup process in the frontend but I don't like doing this. Because my signup logic needs to save something in my local database as well. I wand them to be in one place. Does anyone know how to handle the usage limit in my case?

Comment: have you tested creating, say 300 random users from your server? I don't believe the rate limit would apply to the admin-sdk.

Comment: @Linxy: from the code in the question it looks like this is using the client SDK (for IoT devices that run Node.js). For administrative/backend processes, using the Admin SDK is indeed the solution. Do you feel like writing that into an answer, so we can upvote (and hopefully accept if it answer the question)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase-Auth AdminSDK should not be rate limited so you can use it on your NodeJS server without any problems to handle as many user authentications as you require.

Make sure you don't use the client-side javascript SDK, which should not be used on the backend, but instead for frontend consumers like IoT, WebApps, Consumer Desktop Apps..

More info on the difference here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup